# How can I get default value of antd select?

Tags: reactjs, select, antd

I have a simple antd select which has three options ( "Jack", "Lucy" and "Laura"). Lucy is default value. I have h2 that displays value of select when I change any value. When I click "Jack", it displays: "Field value is Jack" and same happens for other two values as well. I am using onChange event to catch the value and then store it in a state and then display it. Problem is I want to display "Field value is lucy" when page loads and I am not able to achieve this. When I change value to other than lucy and again come back to lucy then onChange event captures the value of lucy in state and it gets displayed, but I want to display its value from start, when page loads without changing value other than lucy. How can I extract default value of this antd select?

Here is code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ey3kfq?file=src%2FApp.js,src%2Fstyle.css

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creds for providing a working sample showing the issue.
Here's a fixed solution: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-fekvet?file=src/App.js

The issue is because your `Select` control had a `defaultValue` which didn't align with what was being displayed. The easy fix is to provide `useState` with your intended initial value, and use that as the value for `defaultValue`

Answer (score 0):

You can put default value in your useState to show the default value. Like the below code snippet. Hope this will help you.

```
const DEFAULT_VALUE = 'lucy'

export default function App() {
  ....
  const [fieldValue, setFieldValue] = useState(DEFAULT_VALUE);
  ...
  return (
      ...
      <Select
        defaultValue={DEFAULT_VALUE}
        ....
      >
        ...
      </Select>
      ....
  );
}
```

Comment: Oh this was not hard. I should've sorted this out by myself but wasn't able to. Thanks for your help.